Can'r add "qmlls" on nvim-lsconfig
First of all I am using kickstart.nvim
On :h lspconfig-all, qmlls and qml_lsp. As far as I understand, adding either of them to the 'servers' table of nvim-lsconfig setup should install the language server and load it on the given filetypes.
Instead I get this error:
Error executing vim.schedule lua callback: ...l/share/nvim/lazy/mason.nvim/lua/mason-registry/init.lua:80: Cannot find package "qmlls".
stack traceback:
[C]: in function 'error'
...l/share/nvim/lazy/mason.nvim/lua/mason-registry/init.lua:80: in function 'get_package'
...on-tool-installer.nvim/lua/mason-tool-installer/init.lua:166: in function 'callback'
...share/nvim/lazy/mason.nvim/lua/mason-core/async/init.lua:87: in function 'step'
...share/nvim/lazy/mason.nvim/lua/mason-core/async/init.lua:96: in function 'run'
...l/share/nvim/lazy/mason.nvim/lua/mason-registry/init.lua:202: in function 'refresh'
...on-tool-installer.nvim/lua/mason-tool-installer/init.lua:195: in function ''
vim/_editor.lua: in function ''
vim/_editor.lua: in function <vim/_editor.lua:0>


Welcome to Vim! In order to reproduce your problem we would need a minimal setup (init.lua and friends).
